# Spark: OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, apache-spark, memory, pyspark, heap-memory

I'm currently facing a problem. I am developing with PySpark and I am trying to load a JSON file into a dataframe (~2Go). The problem is that I keep getting this error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I already tried several things:

- Set `-Xmx` to `3g` in the JVM with no effects
- Set different Spark options (in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`) with no effect:

  ```
  spark.executor.memory           3g
  spark.driver.memory             3g
  spark.python.worker.memory      3g
  spark.memory.fraction           0.9
  spark.driver.maxResultSize      3g
  spark.memory.storageFraction    0.9
  ```

This is the code:

```
 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

 def main(sc):
    df = spark.read.json("/path/to/file.json")

 if __name__ == "__main__":
      spark = SparkSession \
         .builder \
         .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
         .getOrCreate()
      main(spark)
```

I call the program with:

```
spark-submit program.py
```

Needless to say that I've checked the total amount of memory available on the server: 8G.

After further researches, I haven't been able to find another solution. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Maybe 3g isn't enough.  I'd run top or task manager or similar to check how much it is actually using before it falls over.

Comment: Well, I tried with a file with a size around 1G and i still have the same problem

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace

Comment: I experience the same issue. I give the driver 10GB and the executors 5GB each and only wanna process a 1GB file. I tried like every combination of settings it seems :D